# I can not display the answer on my tkinter screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I use tkinter to make a converter units. My code does shows an error, but nothing appears on the screen

```
# implement the variable
var1 = DoubleVar()
var2 = StringVar()
var3 = StringVar()

def conver():
              t1 = { "km": 1000,
                     "hm" : 100,
                     "dam": 10,
                      "m": 1,
                      "dm" : 0.1,
                      "cm": 0.01,
                      "mm" : 0.001   }


               t2 = { "kg": 1000,
                      "hg" : 100,
                      "dag": 10,
                      "g" : 1,
                      "dg" : 0.1,
                      "cg": 0.01,
                      "mmg": 0.001}




                 A = var1.get()
                 B = var1.get()
                 C = var3.get()
                 if B in t1.keys() and C in t1.keys():
                                B1 = t1[B]
                                C1 = t1[c]
                                N = A * (B1/C1)
                                text.insert(END, str(N))

                 Number = Entry( Left, bd = 10, text = var1)
                 Number.grid(row = 0)
                 Number1 = Entry( Left, bd = 10, text = var2)
                 Number1.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
                 Number2 = Label( Left, bd 
                 =10,tex"en",font("arial",10,"bold"))
                 Number2.grid(row = 0,column = 2)
                 Number3 = Entry( Left, bd = 10, text = var3)
                 Number3.grid(row = 0,column=3)
                 number4 = Button(Left,font = 
                 ("arial",10,"bold"),text = "Cacul",command = 
                 conver,bg = "SeaGreen1" ,bd = 10)
                 number4.grid(row =10 )

                 Right = Frame(root,bd =10)
                 Right.pack(side= RIGHT)
                 text = Text(Right, bd =10, width = 50, height = 
                 20)
                text.pack(side = RIGHT)
```

I am trying to convert one unit to a specific unit for instance( 1km = 1000m), when I run my code, I see nothing on the screen. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I put my code about. Thank you!

Comment: Show us a [mcve] that we can run and see the error you are having, including imports and correct indentation.

Comment: First print A, B, and C to see what you are using. Then, use "textvariable=" for the Entry, (it is a variable and not some text that you display on the screen).  See "You can also bind the entry widget to a StringVar instance, and set or get the entry text via that variable" at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax `Number2 = Label( Left, bd=10,tex"en",font("arial",10,"bold"))`. Often when there is an error, Tkinter will cause it to not be show. I am guessing you meant `text="en"` and `font=("arial",10,"bold")`, as font is not a function but a keyword.